# Trouble gaining the depth data from Kinect

Tags: java, macos, kinect, jna

I've been messing about all day trying to get the (raw) data from the Kinect with no success.

I've been trying to hack the unit tests into a program of sorts and my Google-fu is letting me down - I couldn't find any other Java examples anywhere on the web using Java/JNA/osX.

This is the test that I've been hacking at but just can't seem to get a method to extract the frame data.

```
 @Test
 public void testDepth() throws InterruptedException {
    assumeThat(dev, is(not(nullValue())));

    final Object lock = new Object();
    final long start = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println(dev.getDepthMode());
    //dev.startDepth(new DepthHandler(){});
    dev.startDepth(new DepthHandler() {
        int frameCount = 0;

        @Override
        public void onFrameReceived(FrameMode mode, ByteBuffer frame, int timestamp) {

            //ByteBuffer frame1 = frame;
            frameCount++;
            byte[] b = new byte[frame.remaining()];
            System.out.println(frameCount);
            System.out.println(frame.capacity());
            //System.out.println(frame.);
            if (frameCount >= 300) {
                synchronized (lock) {
                    lock.notify();
                    System.out.format("Got %d depth frames in %4.2fs%n", frameCount,
                            (((double) System.nanoTime() - start) / 1000000000));
                }
            }
        }
    });
    synchronized (lock) {
        lock.wait(20000);
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: For anyone who is interested or faces a similar problem ; it's to do with the byte buffer and how you extract the int values from it. The data is there in the bytebuffer in the example above but you need to extract it in the right format.

Comment: If the data is in the form of a C struct, then JNA can help you extract it.  If it's just arbitrarily packed data, then you have to pull it out yourself based on sizes and offsets (JNA can still help with Pointer-based methods).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this project: https://github.com/murphydactyl/JavaKinectFingerTracker

The `getDepthFrame` function gives you the Depth data in a usable form: https://github.com/murphydactyl/JavaKinectFingerTracker/blob/9ed9fcb7836276f7ac9c2bf25569c68417158df5/kinectdigitizer/KinectFrameGrabber.java

If you try to run it with the newest version of the jna it won't work; the `onFrameReceived` function changed a bit.